# How to see function attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, attributes

In Python functions (function objects) can have attributes.

For example:

```
def func(a):
    return a*a

func.attr = 1
```

Is there is a way to see this attribute and its value?

I have tried `inspect.getfullargspec` from `inspect` module but it shows only function arguments.

```
FullArgSpec(args=['a'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

Comment: `getfullargspec` is to get the *full* *arg*ument *spec*ification, the parameters the function expects. If you want to see *attributes*, try e.g. `dir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like any other object, you can use `vars`:

```
def func(a):
    return a*a

func.attr = 1

print(vars(func))
# {'attr': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python `vars()` function can be used here to get the entire object

**Code**

```
def func(a):
    return a**3

func.function = "Cubic Function"
func.arguments = "Integers"

print(func(99))

print(vars(func))

print(vars(func)["function"])

print(vars(func)["arguments"])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
970299
{'function': 'Cubic Function', 'arguments': 'Integers'}
Cubic Function
Integers
```